# Criando o seu próprio header file

Tags: c, arquivo-header

Alguém saberia me explicar a utilidade e como criar a header file em c com um exemplo?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A compilação de um programa escrito em C é feita resumidamente em duas etapas:

1. **Compilação:** Traduzir cada source (.c) (chamado **unidade de tradução**) em um objeto (.o)
2. **Linking:** Unir todos os objetos em um programa executável ou biblioteca

O objetivo dessa separação é ganhar tempo. Primeiro que a compilação ocorre em partes, um arquivo por vez, evitando saturar a memória e o tempo de otimização. Depois que você só precisa recompilar os sources que você alterar, não todos.

Dessa forma o compilador não tem nenhuma informação sobre quais são as funções e variáveis expostas pelas outras unidades de tradução, apenas a que ele está lidando no momento. Os arquivos de cabeçalho são a forma de especificar essa interface. O compilador considera que qualquer coisa que você declarar mas não definir será definido em outra unidade. Assim se agrupa essas declarações em arquivos. Ao #incluir um arquivo em outro você está apenas copiando tudo que tem nele. É comum também incluir o cabeçalho no arquivo que o implementa (define suas declarações) como uma forma de provocar erros caso você defina algo diferente do que você inicialmente declarou. Outra utilidade é usar as funções antes que você mesmo as defina. Um exemplo:

`foobar.h`:

```
#ifndef FOOBAR_H   // guardas de cabeçalho, impedem inclusões cíclicas
#define FOOBAR_H

extern int baz;    // declaração de uma variável global
                   // como é global, valor inicial é zero.

int foo(long arg); // declaração de uma função
int bar(void);     // outra

#endif
```

`foobar.c`:

```
#include "foobar.h"

int baz; // definição da variável

int foo(long arg) {
    baz += arg;
    return baz + bar() - 2; // só posso chamar bar() aqui porque a declarei antes
}

int bar(void) {
    return 4;
}
```

`main.c`:

```
#include "foobar.c"
#include <stdio.c> // a libc vai definir essas funções

int main() {
    printf("%d\n", foo(2)); // 4
    printf("%d\n", foo(2)); // 6
    baz = 3;
    printf("%d\n", foo(2)); // 7
}
```

Assumindo que você esteja usando o gcc, compile assim:

```
gcc -c foobar.c -o foobar.o
gcc -c main.c -o main.o
gcc foobar.o main.o -o meuprograma
```

Answer (score 6):

Arquivos header, de cabeçalho, são bibliotecas, nelas há coleção de funções. É exatamente igual a `stdio.h`, `string.h` e demais bibliotecas comumente utilizadas, nestas a inclusão no arquivo **.c** é feita com os símbolos **<>**, `#include <stdio.h>`, porque o arquivo `stdio.h` está localizado em uma pasta chamada **include**, que por sua vez está dentro da pasta do compilador.

Quando o arquivo header está fora desta pasta do compilador, mas na mesma repartição do código que irá utiliza-lo, usa-se aspas duplas, desta forma: `#include "minhaBiblioteca.h"`. Caso o arquivo esteja em outra pasta, você precisará informar passo-a-passo o caminho entre aspas dupla e usando o **/** para ir acessando até a pasta de destino do arquivo **.h** a ser utilizado, como no prompt de comando.

### Benefícios:

1. **Reutilização de código**. Fica mais fácil depois, em um projeto, reutilizar funções pré feitas e compiladas, não é preciso reimplementá-las.
2. **Organização**. Omitindo a implementação, apenas a lógica utilizada no arquivo principal é vista pelo programador, há menos linhas para analisar. E pressupõe-se, que as funções estão corretas, é bom ponto de partida para achar futuros erros na utilização delas.
3. **Omissão da implementação** das funções, classes e/ou métodos. Com isso, o usuário limita-se à interface da biblioteca, não tem ideia da implementação, e você acaba tendo sigilo sobre a técnica utilizada, que pode ser só sua. Isso também evita alterações indevidas e, de certa forma, usos inapropriados, já que você especifica como usar certa função.

### Organização:

No arquivo **helloWorld.h** você coloca protótipos, variáveis, enfim, declarações.

```
 #ifndef HELLOWORLD_H
 #define HELLOWORLD_H

 void helloWorld();

 #endif
```

No arquivo **helloWorld.c** você fará as implementações.

```
 #include "helloWorld.h"
 #include <stdio.h>

 void helloWorld()
 {
    printf("Hello World!");
 }
```

E no **main.c**, o arquivo principal, fará o uso propriamente dito do que foi implementado no arquivo **helloWorld.c**.

```
 #include "helloWorld.c"

 int main(void)
 {
    helloWorld();
    return 0;
 }
```

A **sequência de compilação** deve ser, obviamente, em primeiro a implementação (**helloWorld.c**), para depois você poder usá-lo - estou considerando aqui o uso de uma IDE como *Code::Blocks*, que compila e linkedita diretamente, gerando diretamente o executável e executando-o, inclusive.

Há ainda a possibilidade de compilar no prompt de comando, a ordem de compilação não interessa desta forma, pois os cabeçalhos serão incluídos na linkedição dos códigos objetos (**.o**) e não na compilação, processo que será feito sobre o código em Linguagem C (**.c**).

```
gcc -c main.c -o main.o
gcc -c helloWorld.c -o helloWorld.o
gcc main.o helloWorld.o -o helloWorld
```

Answer (score 4):

Arquivos header são utilizados só pra definição do que se quer usar, por exemplo uma função

```
int soma (int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;
}
```

no header ficaria como

```
int soma (int x, int y);
```

e no .c/.cpp ficaria

```
int soma (int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;
}
```

porque quando se da include nos headers, você está à procura da definição das funções/variáveis, e não a implementação dela, que no caso fica armazenada nos arquivos .obj se não me engano na hora da compilação...

isso evita o compilador de ficar recompilando código toda hora...

um exemplo melhor é no caso de uma biblioteca dinâmica (.dll) ou estática (.lib)

você além de precisar da dll (que é o código compilado - igual o .obj), você precisa dos cabeçalhos (headers) que definem as funções à serem utilizadas...

por isso tamém não é recomendável você escrever implementações nos cabeçalhos, pois acelera o processo de compilação caso uma função já tenha sido compilada

espero ter sido claro na explicação!

Comment: Muito obrigado, esclareceu bastante

Comment: para utiliza-lo eu tenho que dar um import, certo? Apenas isso?

Comment: @user2984406 Você vai dar um `#include "seuheader.h"`