# Undefined reference ao compilar múltiplos arquivos

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos

Estou aprendendo C++, e tenho uma dúvida a respeito de criar as classes em diferentes arquivos. Criei o header com protótipos de funções, depois como funções membro em outro arquivo cpp.

Quando vou testar os arquivos junto a um main tenho o seguinte erro:

```
undefined reference to GradeBook::GradeBook(std::string) linha 14
undefined reference to GradeBook::getNomeCurso() linha 16
```

Este é o header com a classe gradebook : gradebook.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class GradeBook
{
public:
    GradeBook( string );
    void setNomeCurso(string);
    string getNomeCurso();
    void mostrarMensagem();

private:
    string nome_curso;
};
```

Este é o arquivo chamado gradebook.cpp com as funções membro nele:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "gradebook.h"

using namespace std;

GradeBook::GradeBook( string z ){
   setNomeCurso(z);
}

void GradeBook::setNomeCurso( string nome ){
    nome_curso = nome;
}

string GradeBook::getNomeCurso(){
    return nome_curso;
}

void GradeBook::mostrarMensagem(){
    cout << "Bem vindo ao Livro de " << getNomeCurso() << "!" << endl;
}
```

E este é o arquivo teste.cpp com a funcao Main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "gradebook.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string curso;

    cout << "Entre com o nome do curso : ";
    getline(cin, curso);
    cout << endl;

    GradeBook Livro( curso );

    cout << "Bem vindo ao curso de " << Livro.getNomeCurso() << endl;

}
```

Comment: Qual comando foi utilizado para compilar?

Comment: Pois é, parece que você não compilou/linkou o gradebook.cpp junto com o teste.cpp.

Comment: Você precisa gerar o objeto compilado da classe antes de compilar o programa principal. Está usando Windows ou Linux? Alguma IDE? Compilando na mão?

Comment: estou usando o codeblocs no windows, vou dar uma pesquisada sobre compilar o objeto, obrigado

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Voce deve compilar cada arquivo *.cpp* em um objeto *.o*. Em sequida linkar os objetos em um binário final. O seu problema ocorre porque você compilou apenas o arquivo main e no momento de criar o executável algumas funções estavam faltando (as do *gradebook.cpp*). Assumindo que você está a usar o GCC, faça o seguinte:

```
g++ -c main.cpp
g++ -c gradebook.cpp
g++ main.o gradebook.o -o programa
```

Ou, simplesmente:

```
g++ main.cpp gradebook.cpp -o programa
```

Leitura recomendada: [Criando o seu próprio header file](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3690/criando-o-seu-proprio-header-file) (embora essa seja sobre C, não C++)

Comment: estou usando o codeblocks em windows, vou dar uma pesquisada sobre compilar em .o , obrigado.

Answer (score 4):

Assumindo que você está utilizando o GCC ou algum compilador com interface similar, faça, na linha de comando:

```
$ g++ -c gradebook.cpp -o gradebook.o
$ g++ Main.cpp gradebook.o -o <nome_do_programa>
```

Você pode facilitar sua vida usando o GNU Make (para Linux) ou ferramentas como o CMake que são compatíveis com o Windows e fazer:

Makefile:

```
main: Main.cpp gradebook.o
    g++ $^ -o <nome_do_programa>

%.o: %.cpp
    g++ -c $^
```

Na linha de comando:

```
$ make main
```

Answer (score 0):

Aqui parece estar funcionando.

```
g++ Main.cpp gradebook.cpp
```